# LibreOffice confined by Firejail ignores all keystrokes

Tags: keyboard, libreoffice, firejail

This is going to sound crazy, but today LibreOffice ignores all keystrokes. It was working a few days ago. I opened a spreadsheet to make a modification, but couldn't change any cells. Then I make a new Text Document, which appears as a blank document, but I can't type into it.

My keyboard is working as you can see, as I am using it to type this message. I deleted the config directory:

```
rm -rf ~/.config/libreoffice
```

I restarted my PC. Still nothing. All other apps work, but in LibreOffice I can't use the keyboard to open a new file (Ctrl+O) nor quit (Ctrl+Q). I can do those actions using the mouse.

If I make a new Presentation, it creates it OK, and I can "Click to add text" but once those words have disappeared, and I have a blinking cursor, I cannot type anything.

Any suggestions?

LibreOffice version:

```
LibreOffice 7.3.7.2
```

Ubuntu version:

```
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04.3 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
VERSION_CODENAME=jammy
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
```

---

**EDIT**

It appears to be related to FireJail. Disabling it for LibreOffice fixed the issue. There must be some configuration issue for FireJail that stops it sending keystrokes to LibreOffice. Any hints on how to fix that?